Optimize VBA code on lookup without using Vlookup
Source

Target

i have two column in source with 200 rows. In target sheet, have 300 rows. Need to create a lookup from Target to Source to get 2nd column value from Source sheet. I don't want to use VLOOKUP. Currently i am doing thru loop :
 For i =1 to lastrow of Target tab
  for j=1 to lastrow of source tab
   if target.cells(i,1) = source.cells(j,1) then
     target.cells(i,2)= source.cells(j,2)
   exit for
    end if
 next j
next i

This code take too much time as i have 200 columns in source to copy and paste to target tab. Just need any optimization code for the same. Also target tab have more rows compared to source tab data.

What's wrong with Vlookup?

Is this will fast? Also applying dynamic vlookup on 200 columns is time taking.

Your loop is an extremely slow approach. Vlookup should be faster.

Should take no time at all, just make sure to use Absolute and relative references as needed. If you really must avoid using VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH (why reinvent the wheel?) consider using Range.Find

Read both columns (or both sheets, if there are multiple columns involved) into arrays and loop the arrays.

@cybernetic.nomad pls share sample

@timwilliams pls do share d code for 1 column lookup

A VBA Lookup: Lookup Data Using Worksheet Functions

Sub LookupData()

    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Source")
    Dim slrg As Range: ' lookup
    Set slrg = sws.Range("A2", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns("B") ' return
    
    ' Target
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Sheets("Target")
    Dim tlrg As Range: ' lookup
    Set tlrg = tws.Range("A2", tws.Cells(tws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Dim trrg As Range: Set trrg = tlrg.EntireRow.Columns("B") ' return

    ' Lookup
    With Application
        trrg.Value = .IfNa(.Index(srrg, .Match(tlrg, slrg, 0)), "")
        ' in MS365
        'trrg.Value = .XLookup(tlrg, slrg, srrg, "")
    End With

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data looked up.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

A Test

Your code is slow because you're accessing the cells too many times.
Here is a sub mimicking your code. Run it to better understand why your code is slow.

Sub LookupDataSlow()
    
    ' Workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Source")
    Dim sLastRow As Long: ' lookup
    sLastRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Target
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Sheets("Target")
    Dim tLastRow As Long: ' lookup
    tLastRow = tws.Cells(tws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim sRow As Long, tRow As Long
    Dim ReadCount As Long, WriteCount As Long
    
    For tRow = 2 To tLastRow
        For sRow = 2 To sLastRow
            ReadCount = ReadCount + 2
            If sws.Cells(sRow, "A").Value = tws.Cells(tRow, "A").Value Then
                ReadCount = ReadCount + 1
                WriteCount = WriteCount + 1
                tws.Cells(tRow, "B").Value = sws.Cells(sRow, "B").Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next sRow
    Next tRow
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Slow Data Lookup" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & "ReadCount: " & ReadCount & vbLf _
        & "WriteCount: " & WriteCount & vbLf _
        & "TotalCount: " & ReadCount + WriteCount, vbInformation
    
End Sub


On my small data set (see screenshot above), with Exit For, the sheet was accessed 82 times while without it even 116 times. Let us know how many times it was accessed when it ran on your data set.


I tested both codes on 2009 sources/6027 targets. The elapsed time is 0 in both cases.

@rotabor Your data set is still 'peanuts' for Excel. You could test 100k or 1M rows to detect a reasonable difference.

2009 sources/192864 targets: 18 s mine, 2 s yours.

If you want to do this optimally, this is where data structures come into play. The current implementation is O(n^2). You'd be better off using a dictionary to speed this up:
'Create lookup
Dim v: v = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source").UsedRange.Value
Dim lookup as Object: set lookup = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim i as long
For i = 2 to ubound(v,1)
  lookup(v(i,1)) = v(i,2)
next

'Update Target via lookup
Dim rTarget as Range: set rTarget = Application.Intersect(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target").Range("A:A"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target").UsedRange)
set rTarget = rTarget.resize(rTarget.rows.countlarge - 1).offset(1)
v = rTarget.value
For i = 1 to ubound(v,1)
  v(i,1) = lookup(v(i,1))
next
rTarget.offset(0,1).value = v

This code is O(n*log(n)) which is significantly fewer calculations. Additionally I would recommend:

Creating tables for your data (see ribbon button Insert > Tables > Table). Then name your table.
Name the worksheets in the VBE. (see View > Properties window; if it isn't visible)



This improves code quality:
'Create lookup
Dim v: v = Source.Range("Source").value
Dim lookup as Object: set lookup = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim i as long
For i = 1 to ubound(v,1)
  lookup(v(i,1)) = v(i,2)
next

'Update Target via lookup
v = Target.Range("Target").value
For i = 1 to ubound(v,1)
  v(i,2) = lookup(v(i,1))
next
Target.Range("Target").value = v


The first step to make it much faster is to copy the source and the target to respective arrays:
Sub scsad()
  Dim ti As Long, si As Long, sl As Long, tl As Long
  Dim target As Worksheet, source As Worksheet, d As Date
  Dim s As Variant, t As Variant
  d = Now()
  Set target = Sheets("Target")
  Set source = Sheets("Source")
  sl = source.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
  tl = target.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
  s = Range(source.Cells(2, 1), source.Cells(sl, 2))
  t = Range(target.Cells(2, 1), target.Cells(tl, 2))
  sl = sl - 1
  tl = tl - 1
  For ti = 1 To tl
    For si = 1 To sl
      If t(ti, 1) = s(si, 1) Then
        t(ti, 2) = s(si, 2)
        Exit For
      End If
    Next si
  Next ti
  Range(target.Cells(2, 1), target.Cells(tl + 1, 2)) = t
  Debug.Print Now() - d
End Sub

Further possible improvement is to sort both the source and the target. In this case it will be O(s+t)+O(s*log(s))+O(t*log(t)) of average complexity.

@vBasic2008 lookup function not working. As there is no loop which i assume.

My bad. Its working perfectly. Thank u @vBasic2008
